# Error running 'splash': The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen

I added a splash screen to my project after MainActivity. I guess it should be start first. How can i set it as first ? Here is my manifest.xml.

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".splash"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch `intent-filter` from `MainActivity` to `splash`.

Below you will find the solution:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
</application>
```

Don't forget to extend `AppCompatActivity` in `splash`.

Also, I recommend to rename `splash` to `SplashActivity`

Comment: How can i extend AppCompatActivitiy ? If you mean 

`public class splashActivity extends AppCompatActivity` i figured it .